# Add a hard wait between every page action

Tags: node.js, playwright

I'm creating test scripts in Playwright and Node.js for an old, buggy web application run by a vendor. I don't have access to the code for the application, my tests run on the vendor's website.

I continually find issues that are solved by adding hard waits. For reasons I don't understand (because I don't have access to the code) the website seems to have trouble with the speed that Playwright performs actions.

I'm wondering if there's a way to add a hard wait between each action? Is it possible to wrap the `page` object in a wrapper that calls `waitForTimeout`, then whatever function was called?

Comment: This [isn't a good idea in browser automation](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-page#page-wait-for-timeout) ("DISCOURAGED
Never wait for timeout in production."), but there is a `slowMo` option: https://playwright.dev/docs/debug#headed-mode. Even if it's an old buggy app, you can still use locators or `waitForFunction` to use an event-driven approach that isn't racy or unnecessarily slow. Better to fix your wait predicates than to give up and add big timeouts on everything.

Comment: If you have to timeout, better to add a specific timeout per step--more code, but at least you don't have to take the hit of the global worst-case timeout value on each and every operation. Many ops may not need timeouts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is 2 fold answer to it:

#### 1) Set [action and navigation timeouts](https://playwright.dev/docs/test-timeouts#set-action-and-navigation-timeouts-in-the-config) in the config

to increase timeout for every action including navigations.

```
import { defineConfig } from '@playwright/test';

export default defineConfig({
  use: {
    actionTimeout: 10 * 1000,
    navigationTimeout: 30 * 1000,
  },
});
```

This can be further overridden on step level if needed:

```
locator.click({ timeout: 10000 })
```

#### 2) [Record the trace](https://playwright.dev/docs/trace-viewer-intro#recording-a-trace)

to find out exactly what steps are *taking more time* and *which don't* and you can go from there to further explore the root cause as needed

```
import { defineConfig } from '@playwright/test';
export default defineConfig({
  retries: process.env.CI ? 2 : 0, // set to 2 when running on CI
  ...
  use: {
    trace: 'on-first-retry', // record traces on first retry of each test
  },
});
```

#### Recommended Approach:

> One may tempt to use hard wait as standard approach in automation to get rid
> of all sync issues but this is **NOT** recommended. I would suggest to
> use it to confirm functionality is working and measure performance of
> specific steps to pinpoint to dev team so that they can address the
> underlying issues.

In general , playwright's auto-waiting feature is good enough for most of the healthy applications out there.